# Problem with java scanner exception inside java container

Tags: java, docker

I have weird problem with java scanner exception inside docker. When I compile it normally in InteliJ everything is okey. But when I run serwer inside of container and then client side I am getting something like that

Client exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at Client.main(Client.java:29)
```

Server exception:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:346)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:595)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:570)
at APIGateway$ClientHandler.run(APIGateway.java:74)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

And next I will show you how my Dockerfile looks like. Please, don't be scared it is my first try with this technology.

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /code

#API
#COPY /out/artifacts/Tech_jar/Tech.jar /tmp

#Client
COPY /out/artifacts/Tech_jar2/Tech.jar /tmp

EXPOSE 1000
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /tmp/Tech.jar
```

And then there is my code:

client (line 29 --- first scaner inside of the while loop):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

// Client class
class Client {

    // driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // establish a connection by providing host and port
        // number
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1000)) {

            // writing to server
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // reading from server
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // object of scanner class
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String line = null, toSend = "", username = null, password, message;
            boolean state = false;

            while (!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                toSend = "";
                menu();
                line = sc.nextLine();
                switch(line){
                    case "1":
                        if(!state){
                            toSend += "mode:login";

                            System.out.print("Podaj login: ");
                            username = sc.nextLine();
                            toSend += "#login:" + username;

                            System.out.print("Podaj hasło: ");
                            password = sc.nextLine();
                            toSend += "#password:" + password;

                            out.writeUTF(toSend);
                            out.flush();

                            if(in.readUTF().split(":")[1].equals("0")){
                                state = true;
                                System.out.println("Zalogowano");
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Login lub hasło jest niepoprawne");
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Jesteś już zalogowany");
                        }

                        break;
                    case "2":
                        if(!state){
                            toSend += "mode:registration";

                            System.out.print("Podaj login: ");
                            String usernameR = sc.nextLine();
                            toSend += "#login:" + usernameR;

                            System.out.print("Podaj hasło: ");
                            password = sc.nextLine();
                            toSend += "#password:" + password;

                            out.writeUTF(toSend);
                            out.flush();

                            if(in.readUTF().split(":")[1].equals("0")){
                                System.out.println("Konto zostało utowrzone");
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Login jest zajęty");
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Jesteś już zalogowany");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        if(state){
                            toSend += "mode:chat#username:";
                            toSend += username;

                            System.out.print("Napisz wiadomość: ");
                            message = sc.nextLine();
                            toSend += "#message:" + message;

                            System.out.println(toSend);
                            out.writeUTF(toSend);
                            out.flush();

                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Nie jesteś zalogowany");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        toSend += "mode:table";
                        out.writeUTF(toSend);
                        out.flush();
                        String[] response = in.readUTF().split("#");
                        for (String msg : response) {
                            System.out.println(msg);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        if(state) {
                            toSend += "mode:uploading";
                            out.writeUTF(toSend);
                            System.out.print("Podaj nazwę pliku: ");
                            String path = sc.nextLine();
                            out.writeUTF(path);
                            File file = new File(path);

                            if (file.exists()) {
                                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                                int FileLength = (int) file.length();
                                out.writeInt(FileLength);
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[FileLength];
                                fis.read(buffer);
                                out.write(buffer);
                                out.flush();
                                fis.close();
                                if(in.readUTF().split(":")[1].equals("0")){
                                    System.out.println("Pomyślnie przesłano plik na serwer");
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("Coś poszło nie tak");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Plik nie istnieje");
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Nie jesteś zalogowany");
                        }
                    case "6":
                        if(state) {
                            toSend += "mode:downloading";
                            out.writeUTF(toSend);
                            System.out.print("Podaj nazwę pliku: ");
                            String path = sc.nextLine();
                            out.writeUTF(path);
                            File file = new File(path);

                            if (file.exists()) {
                                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Czarek\\IdeaProjects\\TechnologieSiecioweProjekt\\FileServer\\" + file);
                                int FileLength = (int) file.length();
                                out.writeInt(FileLength);
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[FileLength];
                                fis.read(buffer);
                                out.write(buffer);
                                out.flush();
                                fis.close();
                                if(in.readUTF().split(":")[1].equals("0")){
                                    System.out.println("Pomyślnie pobrano plik");
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("Coś poszło nie tak");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Plik nie istnieje");
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Nie jesteś zalogowany");
                        }
                    case "7":
                        System.out.println("Wylogowałeś się");
                        state = false;
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        System.out.println("Dobranoc");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Nie ma takiej opcji");
                }
            }

            // closing the scanner object
            sc.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void menu(){
        System.out.println("\nMENU\n1. Logowanie\n2. Rejestracja\n3. Chat\n4. Tablica\n5. Wysyłanie plików\n6. Pobieranie plików\n7. Wylogowywanie\n8. Exit");
    }

}
```

Server (line 74 --- first in.readUTF inside of while(74 line) ):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

// Server class
class APIGateway {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ServerSocket server = null;

        try {

            // server is listening on port 1234
            server = new ServerSocket(1000);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);

            // running infinite loop for getting
            // client request
            while (true) {

                // socket object to receive incoming client
                // requests
                Socket client = server.accept();

                // Displaying that new client is connected
                // to server
                System.out.println("New client connected"+ client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

                // create a new thread object
                ClientHandler clientSock= new ClientHandler(client);

                // This thread will handle the client
                // separately
                new Thread(clientSock).start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ClientHandler class
    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        // Constructor
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            DataInputStream in = null;
            try {

                // get the outputstream of client
                out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                // get the inputstream of client
                in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                String line, mode;
                while ((line = in.readUTF()) != null) {
                    mode = line.split("#")[0].split(":")[1];
                    switch (mode){
                        case "login":
                            Socket loginSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1001);
                            DataOutputStream loginOut = new DataOutputStream(loginSocket.getOutputStream());
                            DataInputStream loginIn = new DataInputStream(loginSocket.getInputStream());
                            loginOut.writeUTF(line);
                            out.writeUTF(loginIn.readUTF());
                            loginIn.close();
                            loginOut.close();
                            break;
                        case "registration":
                            Socket registrationSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1002);
                            DataOutputStream registrationOut = new DataOutputStream(registrationSocket.getOutputStream());
                            DataInputStream registrationIn = new DataInputStream(registrationSocket.getInputStream());
                            registrationOut.writeUTF(line);
                            out.writeUTF(registrationIn.readUTF());
                            registrationIn.close();
                            registrationOut.close();
                            break;
                        case "chat":
                            Socket chatSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1003);
                            DataOutputStream chatOut = new DataOutputStream(chatSocket.getOutputStream());
                            DataInputStream chatIn = new DataInputStream(chatSocket.getInputStream());
                            chatOut.writeUTF(line);
                            chatIn.close();
                            chatOut.close();
                            break;
                        case "table":
                            Socket tableSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1004);
                            DataOutputStream tableOut = new DataOutputStream(tableSocket.getOutputStream());
                            DataInputStream tableIn = new DataInputStream(tableSocket.getInputStream());
                            tableOut.writeUTF(line);
                            out.writeUTF(tableIn.readUTF());
                            tableIn.close();
                            tableOut.close();
                            break;
                        case "uploading":
                            Socket uploadSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1005);
                            DataOutputStream uploadOut = new DataOutputStream(uploadSocket.getOutputStream());
                            DataInputStream uploadIn = new DataInputStream(uploadSocket.getInputStream());

                            uploadOut.writeUTF(line);
                            uploadOut.writeUTF(in.readUTF());
                            int FileLength = in.readInt();
                            uploadOut.writeInt(FileLength);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[FileLength];
                            in.read(buffer);
                            uploadOut.write(buffer);
                            out.writeUTF(uploadIn.readUTF());
                            uploadIn.close();
                            uploadOut.close();
                            break;
                        case "downloading":
                            Socket downloadSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1005);
                            DataOutputStream downloadOut = new DataOutputStream(downloadSocket.getOutputStream());
                            DataInputStream downloadIn = new DataInputStream(downloadSocket.getInputStream());

                            downloadOut.writeUTF(line);
                            downloadOut.writeUTF(in.readUTF());
                            int DownloadFileLength = in.readInt();
                            downloadOut.writeInt(DownloadFileLength);
                            byte[] DownloadBuffer = new byte[DownloadFileLength];
                            in.read(DownloadBuffer);
                            downloadOut.write(DownloadBuffer);
                            out.writeUTF(downloadIn.readUTF());
                            downloadIn.close();
                            downloadOut.close();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And additionaly I have question about connecting mysql database to containers of my project

Comment: The server error occurs because the client throws an exception and terminates abnormally. Do you run the container with the `-i` (interactive) flag?

Comment: Right after I posted i find somewhere solution... But right now i have another problem I don't know how to connect other services. I tried with login but client side stop working :(